# AsyncImage not loading inside VStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

When using an `AsyncImage` inside a `VStack`, the image never loads.  The handler is called once, and the `AsyncImagePhase` is `.empty`.  Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebb78f77c5583ae99472dd4a49")!) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .success(let image):
                    image
                default: EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If you remove the `VStack`, the image loads (only when you run the app though; the Simulator in the Canvas window disappears in this case.)

I assume this is a SwiftUI bug.  Any known workarounds?

Comment: Well, you're force unwrapping your url, though unlikely to cause the problem. Are you actually hitting the `.success` case? Also, is `image` a type of `View`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, replacing `EmptyView()` : (note there is no need for the "!" for the url)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebb78f77c5583ae99472dd4a49")) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .success(let image):
                    image
                default: Color.clear // <-- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work, but I don't understand why...random magical fix or is there a reason?

Comment: as far as I know, `EmptyView` represents the absence of a view, but the `AsyncImage` expect to show some sort of view. But then again, it's all magic to me. You could also replace the `Color.clear` with the more appropriate `ProgressView()`

Comment: But `EmptyView` conforms to `View`, so...not sure why it would cancel the load :shrug:

Comment: Interesting issue! Even if you would only use `AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebb78f77c5583ae99472dd4a49"))` without callback, the image wouldn't load on iOS 15.

On iOS 16, it seems to be resolved.